# react-select does not "fire" the `onChange` handler

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-select

I have a `DropDown` component that renders a `react-select` dropdown and utilizes a custom hook in order to open/close.

**Custom Hook**

```js
import { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';

const useCloseOnClickOutside = (initialState) => {
  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(initialState);
  const ref = useRef(null);

  /**
   * Attach Event Listeners
   */
  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('click', handleClick, true);
    document.addEventListener('touchstart', handleClick, true);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('click', handleClick, true);
      document.removeEventListener('touchstart', handleClick, true);
    };
  },[]);


  const handleClick = (event) => {
    if (!ref.current)
      return;

    // If someone clicks outside the component close the state
    if (!ref.current?.contains(event.target)) {
      setIsVisible(false);
    } else {
      // If someone click on the component toggle the state
      setIsVisible((prevState => !prevState));
    }
  };

  return {
    ref,
    isVisible
  };

};

export default useCloseOnClickOutside;
```

**Dropdown**

```js
import React from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';
import useCloseOnClickOutside from '../../hooks/useCloseOnClickOutside';

const Dropdown = ({handleChange, defaultValue, options, value}) => {
  const {ref,isVisible} = useCloseOnClickOutside(false);

  return (
    <div ref={ref}>
      <Select
        options={options}
        onChange={handleChange}
        defaultValue={defaultValue}
        value={value}
        menuIsOpen={isVisible}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

I pass the `ref` from `useCloseOnClickOutside` to an outer div of `Select` in order to catch the bubble events.

The `handleChange` callback that I pass to `Select` `onChange` does nothing at the moment:

`const handleChange = (val) => console.log(val)`

And call it like this:

**Parent Component**

```js
const ParentComponent = () => {

// All theese are just mocked data
const mockedOptions = [];
const handleChange = (val) => console.log(val);
const mockedDefaultValue = 'default-value';
const mockedValue = stateValue;

return (
  <Dropdown 
  handleChange={handleChange} 
  options={mockedOptions}
  defaultValude={mockedDefaultValue}
  value={mockedValue}
/>
)
}
```

The issue is that at the moment I pass the `ref` to the parent div, `onChange` does not fire at all. If I remove it, it runs successfully. I cant find any reason why this should be happening. Could this be an issue of `react-select` ??

Comment: How do you pass props ` handleChange ` to `Dropdown`. Please show detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw the problem is you are using the `capture` pharse in the `addEventListener`. So `setIsVisible(false);` will be call before `onChange`. So `onChange` will not call when select was hidden.

I saw you have two solution to fix.

Remove `capture` phase:

```
document.addEventListener("click", handleClick);
```

Or delay setTimeOut to make sure it call after `onChange`:

```
setTimeout(() => setIsVisible(false), 0);
```

Comment: you are 100% correct. Removing the capture phrase I guess its the most correct solution.

Comment: @IseNgaRt yeah that is accurate

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to set `menuIsOpen` to false after react-select triggers the `onChange` event.
It looks like if the select is hidden then `onChange` event not trigged
So you might need to add a delay to your custom hook. Then the select will be hidden just after it triggers the `onChange`

```
setTimeout(() => setIsVisible(false));
////
setTimeout(() => setIsVisible((prevState => !prevState)));
```

PS: I'm not sure you need a custom hook to decide the open state of the select, Since it's the default behavior of the react-select

Comment: @IseNgaRt I think answer by Viet is much more details than my answer, so you might mark his answer as correct :)